# High CPU usage with systemd-journal 219 on CentOS

Tags: centos, systemd, journald

systemd-journal seems to have hig CPU usage, compare to HAProxy that is the actual service on the node:

```
385   root      20   0   69948  26152  25776 S   3.0  0.2   0:04.05 systemd-journal
22509 haproxy   20   0   58264   7256   1812 S   1.3  0.0   0:00.45 haproxy
```

CPU:

```
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 63
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x25
cpu MHz         : 2400.139
cache size      : 30720 KB
```

OS:

```
Linux ip-172-33-30-32.eu-central-1.compute.internal 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 3 00:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Systemd:

```
systemd-219-30.el7_3.7.x86_64
systemd-libs-219-30.el7_3.7.x86_64
systemd-sysv-219-30.el7_3.7.x86_64
```

Is there a way to optimize systemd-journal to have lower CPU usage? Is this supposed to be normal for logging to use this much CPU?

Comment: You show no actual evidence of "high CPU usage"  of `systemd-journal`. You have one process using 3.0% of one of the 12 cores of that CPU and one that uses 1.3%. The journal has used 4.05 secs CPU time since the start of the system (how long ago was that?) and the `haproxy` a little bit less but it was also started way later (pid 385 vs 22509). So, what is your problem really?

Comment: I think it is high compare to HAProxy.

Comment: Then you have wrong expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it doesn't seems much of high cpu-usage.

`journald`, has a more complex workflow than `rsyslogd`, since it process and keep the data in a more structured form. If you have very high log output to the `journald`by your services, it is normal that `journald`is overloaded.

In order to optimize journald; Journald has following settings as defaults within following file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/journald.conf

   #RateLimitInterval=30s
   #RateLimitBurst=1000
```

If your service logs are non-critical, you can lower the rate limits to suspend the logs of the service which overloads the `journald`. It also comes with disadvantage that you may lose your logs. Which you will be notifed by `journald`stating the suspended log counts within `RateLimitInterval`, as an enrty instead of logs which are suspended.

Setting does to "0" will disable suspending, and you will have much higher cpu-usage.

If logs are important for you seperate service logs from `journald` and use `rsyslogd`. But again this is not high cpu-usage.